# Removing characters in chain according to an other column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a df like :

```
products                  price 
abc|abc|abc|abc|abc       1|2|10|20|30
abc|abc|deg|              3|8|5
abc|abc|abc|abc|abc|abc   10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18
```

Explication : Each rows is a basket buy by a customers.
              All products is seperate by '|', so for example
              the first customer (row) took 5 products for 63 $.
So normally, a rows contains the same number of '|'.

But as you can see, on the last row, there is 6 products and 9 prices. 
The problem come from the limit of 256 char, so some products are not save on the file, but we have all price for products bought (of course if the column price doesn't exceed 256 CHAR !)

I would like to bring the Price until the max of '|' on the column products and obtain a df like :

```
   products                  price 
abc|abc|abc|abc|abc       1|2|10|20|30
abc|abc|deg|              3|8|5
abc|abc|abc|abc|abc|abc   10|11|12|13|14|15
```

I try this :

```
def count_fx(s):
return s.count('|')

max_prod = max(df['products'].apply(count_fx))

df.ix[np.logical_and(df.products.str.len()==255), ['products']]= df['products'].str.rpartition('|',max_prod)[0]
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you know any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use pandas and numpy for this? It seems like something that can be solved with simple string manipulation. But the best thing would be to fix the cause of the problem. The way you generate the data files is seriously broken.

Comment: Yes because i work on DataFrame and with Numpy i can insert a IF condition on my Fame.

Comment: I'm totally agree with @HåkenLid - you are going to have much more problems with this data model if you won't redesign it...

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split('|', expand=True)` to create a mask on price then recombine:

```
have_products = df.products.str.split('|', expand=True).notnull()

get_price = df.price.str.split('|', expand=True)[have_p]
df.price = get_price.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)

print df

                  products              price
0      abc|abc|abc|abc|abc       1|2|10|20|30
1             abc|abc|deg|              3|8|5
2  abc|abc|abc|abc|abc|abc  10|11|12|13|14|15
```